# Using "on" with "the day (on) which..."

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

> 1. September 3 was the day which I was born.
> 2. September 3 was the day which I was born **on**.
> 3. September 3 was the day **on** which I was born.

Are all of these correct?

Do we have to  use the preposition "on"?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use “on”. Sentence 1 is no good; the other two are ok. The following sounds better, though:

> I was born on September 3.

In any case, you need “on” to precede any specific date.